# Data load to WebView not same chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, android, webview, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to parse this page:

```
http://m.truyentranh8.net/yen-son-phai-va-bach-hoa-mon-chap-77
```

It is a link for the mobile site of a comic. Because the link image generates after some JavaScript executes, I use a WebView to fake to get the string response. Here is code to fake WebView:

```
fakeWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
fakeWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SC-02F Build/LRX21V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36");
fakeWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");

fakeWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       // fakeWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('" + "option value=\"560\" selected"+"', '" + "option value=\"560\""+"')})()");
        //fakeWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('" + "option value=\"360\""+"', '" + "option value=\"360\"  selected"+"')})()");
        fakeWebView.loadUrl("javascript:HTMLOUT.processHTML(document.documentElement.outerHTML);");
    }
});
fakeWebView.loadUrl(chapter.tag);
```

**Then:**

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void processHTML(String html) {
        new AsyncTask<String, Void, Chapter>() {
            @Override
            protected Chapter doInBackground(String... htmlToParse) {
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlToParse[0]);
                ......

                return chapter;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Chapter chapter) {
                super.onPostExecute(chapter);
            }
        }.execute(html);
    }
}
```

Everything looks good except when the image loads from the WebView is not the same when I use my phone in the following scenarios:

- **From webview**: image with big size 1119 × 1600
- **From mobile:** image with small size 540 × 960

Then the image loads very slowly. I tried changing the `user-agent` to `mobile`.